# Asymmetry vs. Simple Statistics WRT Matter / Antimatter Ratios

Tags: antimatter, matter, baryogenesis

I'm not clear on why physicists suspect, and are looking for, an asymmetry in nature that favors matter over antimatter.  Here's a simple thought experiment to illustrate my confusion:  Assume I have a "fair" coin.  I flip the coin 2 billion times and keep track of the results.  If, when I'm done, I have 999,999,999 tails and 1,000,000,001 heads.  I don't start suspecting that nature has a built in asymmetry that favors heads.  So why do physicists suspect there is an asymmetry in nature?  Why can't it just be simple chance that there were more particles of matter than antimatter?

Comment: What process do you propose chooses mater or antimatter randomly? That's a nice analogy if there was a random selection process, but the ones we know are deterministic.

Comment: @dmckee So are you saying that all matter production always generates *pairs* of matter/antimatter?  If that's true, then wouldn't the asymmetry (if there is one) violate the matched pair rule.  And if it's not true, then chance could prevail.  Yes?

Comment: Uhm ... I misspoke. Typed. Whatever. We get all pairs, except for a very small number of known CP-violating processes, and in those we can measure a *consistent* asymmetry. It not like we did one 2-billion-flips trial and got a 1e-9 asymmetry. It's like we've done tens of 2-billion-flips trials and got a 1e-9 asymmetry every time. The problem is that the known processes are too weak by many orders of magnitude to result in the universe we see starting from the theories that are otherwise very solid. So the question is *"Where is the majority of the asymmetry coming from?"*.